# How to create mock LDAP server for Django project?

Tags: python, django, mocking, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I'm using [django-auth-ldap](http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/index.html) and was wondering what is the easiest way to create a python mock ldap server. The problem arises when I'm developing away from the network the ldap server is located on. Testing is another scenario. I want to avoid creating an instance of an actual ldap server locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

django-auth-ldap's tests.py includes a simple mock ldap for its own tests. This was spun off by someone else into the [fakeldap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fakeldap) package, although I haven't been following progress. The right answer is probably to start with fakeldap and contribute if necessary.

UPDATE: A [more serious effort](https://bitbucket.org/psagers/mockldap) to spin off a mock LDAP layer is currently underway.

Comment: Thanks! That project looks interesting, will give it a go.